# What is conditional likelihood?

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, garch

In my course book in time series I read that we usually use conditional likelihood to fit an ARCH model because the likelihood function is usually rather complicated.

What is conditional likelihood?

Comment: Can you add a reference?

Comment: I'm affraid I cannot, because it's a course book written by my lecturer. But the term conditional likelihood apears also in Financial Econometrics from Basics to Advanced Modelling Techniques. Here you've got a screenshot: https://ibb.co/bW67z5P